# How to send data back to cloud for immediate opertions

Tags: c#, architecture, asp.net-web-api2, signalr, .net-core

This is my first architecture attempt so please stay with me. Here is my first attempt,

[image]

Now I will have two types of operations going from Cloud to on premises, both will be connected using VPN,

- Long running operations might take several hours
- Immediate operations like get list of orders from database (don't need to go to job database)

In my architecture I am struggling to figure out how to send data back to cloud for short or immediate running operations.

Let say User A wants list of orders immediately, I make a call to on premises web api, should it use signalR to return immediate data as well ? data might consists 1 record or several hundred ?

In other words, Is there anyway I can send data immediately if it takes less then 3 minutes ? and if it takes longer then workers uses notification service to update cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sync framework to handle all those operations, be in 1 second or 2 days.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490616.aspx

It will also keep your data cool when your VPN drops connection, you can check as much as you need and it will send the data over when the connection is back online.